# curtains.js black hole effect in fragment shader

Tags: webgl, fragment-shader, curtains.js

i am trying to get a kind of a black hole effect where the chessboard gets sucked into the middle of the frame, like in the image below:

[image]

In the main FS function I have this:

```
vec4 mapEffect = texture2D(displacementTexture1, vTextureCoord);
vec4 finalColor = texture2D(sourceImage, vDisplacedTextureCoord + mapEffect.xy);
gl_FragColor = finalColor;
```

But i only get this no matter how i tweak the values and the operators.

[image]

I would appreciate a small hint on how to proceed :)

Comment: What you're looking to create is called a "pinch" effect, you can see implementations on shadertoy.